# CouchDB requires PUT for adding attachment to document, but AppMobi.file.uploadToServer() does POST

Tags: couchdb, appmobi

to restate the title, CouchDB requires PUT for adding an attachment to document, but AppMobi.file.uploadToServer() does a POST.  CouchDB returns:

```
{"error":"method_not_allowed","reason":"Only DELETE,GET,HEAD,PUT allowed"}
```

I have verified that this is how CouchDB expects it.  I was using uploadToServer to attach an image to a document.  All the CouchDB documents are so-called JSON documents, so any images have to be attachments to an existing document.  I wiresharked the communications and read about uploadToServer and it's definitely doing a POST.  Is there any way I can modify this to a PUT?

Thanks.

Comment: I see that one can modify the method for many web servers (including CouchDb) by adding the X-HTTP-Method-Override header, and setting it, in my case to PUT.  Unfortunately I cannot see any method to add a header to the request that uploadToServer() will make.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: For those interested, relevant follow up to this question may be found at [http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?t=3493](http://forums.appmobi.com/viewtopic.php?t=3493)

Comment: This sort of thing wouldn't be appMobi anymore since they sold some of their assets to Intel. Now check out http://html5dev-software.intel.com/.  There's no issue on the forum related to this yet.